# Grouped aggregations with Yii STAT?

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii, aggregate-functions

I have a [Yii STAT Relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) that's defined to provide a grouped `SUM` result, *however when I access the relation in my View*, the **only value is the latest single value rather than each value**.

For example, here's my relation:

```
'total_salaries_by_job' => array(
    self::STAT, 
    'Employee', 
    'department_id', 
    'select' => 'job_type_id, SUM(salary)', 
    'group'=>"job_type_id"
)
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  department_id AS c
, job_type_id
, SUM(salary) AS s 
FROM Employee AS t
WHERE t.department_id = 1 
GROUP BY 
  department_id
, job_type_id
```

Running that manually, the result set is:

```
c     | job_type_id    | s
------+----------------+---------
1     | 1              | 233000
------+----------------+---------
1     | 2              | 25000
------+----------------+---------
1     | 3              | 179000
```

However, in my view, if I do the following:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($department->total_salaries_by_job); ?>
</pre>
```

The result is simply: `179000`, whereas I was expecting it to be an array with 3 elements.

Is returning just 1 value the way STAT relations work or is there something else I need to be doing?
Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are after, but you can't use a STAT relationship to do it. Rather, use a Normal HAS_MANY relationship and use your same select statement.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to give `SUM(amount)` an **alias**, then create a public variable within the `Employee` model with the alias name.