# Aggregating an array and displaying the aggregation result alongside the detail

Tags: php, arrays, oop, yii

I have a `$department` variable, which is an instance of a `Department` class.

The `Department` class has a property called `$employees` that contains an array of `Employee` instances related to that department (retrieved from the database).

The `Employee` class has a properties called `$salary_amount` and `$job_type_id`. The `$employees` array elements are ordered together by `$job_type_id`.

For a specified department, I'm outputting a list of employees in that department like so:

```
Employees for IT Department
----------------------------

<?php foreach($department->employees as $employee): ?>
  <?php echo $employee->name; ?>
  <?php echo $employee->salary_amount; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**What's an efficient way to manipulate** `$department->employees` **so I can display a sum-total of the** `$salary_amount` **for each** `$job_type_id` **alongside the list of employees?**

```
Employees for IT Department
----------------------------

## Help Desk ##

Joseph Lazar
$47,000

John Q. Smith
$15,444

--> Total Salary for Help Desk: $62,444


## Database Administrator ##

Piet Pietersen
$55,120

Ivan Horvat
$63,750

--> Total Salary for Help Desk: $118,870
```

**Current Approach**

Currently, `$employees` is being populated by a single SQL query, ordering the results how I want. I'm then running a separate SQL query to get an array of `$salary` sum-totals for each `$job_type_id` using a technique from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394954/grouped-aggregations-with-yii-stat).

However, the resultset from this 2nd query is stored in a different variable `$subtotals`. Therefore, I still have the problem of efficiently getting the Sum-Total to display "in-context" with the list of employees.

I happen to be using [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com), however that's probably irrelevant unless I should think about or approach this type of problem from a totally different perspective? Please tell me in the comments.

**Update 1**

Here's the current code I'm using, however it feels messy and like there could be a better way. As mentioned above, the aggregation is done by a separate SQL, however I'm open to alternatives.

```
<?php 

$employee_key = 0;
$employees_count = sizeof($department->employees);

$type_sum_key = 0;
$current_type_in_focus = null;
$next_type_in_focus = null;

foreach($department->employees as $employee)
{
  $current_type_in_focus = $employee->job_type_id;
  $next_type_in_focus = (isset($department->employees[$employee_key+1])) ? $department->employees[$employee_key+1]->job_type_id : null;

  # output individual employee data
  echo $employee->name;
  echo $employee->salary_amount;

  # output aggregated total for job type
  if ( $current_type_in_focus !== $next_type_in_focus || $employee_key+1 == $employees_count )
  {
    echo '--> Total Salary for ' . $employee->jobType->name . ': ' . $department->subtotals[$type_sum_key]->total;
    $type_sum_key++; 
  }

  $income_key++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Can't you just a initialise a variable at `0` and do `$var += $employee->salary_amount` as you loop the data? Then at the end you'll have the amount you want. P.S. You should pay John Q. Smith a bit more, he'll be livid if he see's this - and people with a cool middle initial like Q definitely deserve more :-D

Comment: @DaveRandom Yeah I thought that too. Poor bugger. I am taking the approach you suggest with a `foreach` loop, however it seems clumsy when trying to find where the group of same `$job_type_id`'s end and the next begins so I can output the total in-between. I'm trying to use a bunch of `if-statements`, but the code just gets ugly and doesn't work properly.. so I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to do it tidily with an SQL `GROUP BY` but I can't think of anything that's not a bit nasty in itself. I'll show you want I can think of if you like though...

Comment: In SQL, I could use a Window Aggregate (OLAP) function, but as you say, it's still a bit messy when trying to detect in where to correctly output the value on the page.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm going to add my current code to the question, so then that can be used as a base for improvement. Nice thrashing in the cricket by the way.

Comment: Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b4c9/17) out for some nasty SQL. Basically, convert the data into JSON on the SQL side and decode it in PHP. I'm definitely *not* recommending it as a way forward, simply pointing out that it is theoretically possible. With MySQL at least. And I don't follow cricket that closely but I do know that the English basically suck at all the sports we invented (recent Tennis and Football being casing points), so I'm assuming we lost at the Cricket as well. *edit* Oh I see we won. How odd...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use while loops. For example (for clarity the following code sample does not format the output, also it outputs job_type_id rather than a description as that data is not shown in the question):

```
    $employees = $department->employees;
    $employee = current($employees);

    while($employee)
    {
        $job_type_id = $employee->job_type_id;
        $total_salary = 0;

        echo "## Job Type $job_type_id ##";

        while ($employee && $employee->job_type_id == $job_type_id)
        {
            echo $employee->name;
            echo $employee->salary_amount;
            $total_salary += $employee->salary_amount;
            $employee = next ($employees);
        }

        echo "-->Total Salary for Job Type $job_type_id: $total_salary";
    }
```